# How can I limit interstitial ad opening?

Tags: java, admob, interstitial

I am a newbie in the developing section, recently I'm trying to edit the source code of the web view application. But the problem is every time of "backpress" interstitial ad appears. Which is huge disturbing. Tried to change back press code but after doing that ads totally diseapred. Now I'm confused that how can I solve this problem. Because if a web view app show ads every back press, probably google will not approve it on play store even if accepts then people will not use this app.

I've tried to limit but cannot understand, please help me.
If this is possible the ad shows only one time of back press or at least a limited backpress.

Thanks in advance <3 <3

### mainactivity.java

```
    //Views
    public Toolbar mToolbar;
    public View mHeaderView;
    public TabLayout mSlidingTabLayout;
    public SwipeableViewPager mViewPager;

    //App Navigation Structure
    private NavigationAdapter mAdapter;
    private NavigationView navigationView;
    private SimpleMenu menu;

    private WebFragment CurrentAnimatingFragment = null;
    private int CurrentAnimation = 0;

    //Identify toolbar state
    private static int NO = 0;
    private static int HIDING = 1;
    private static int SHOWING = 2;

    //Keep track of the interstitials we show
    private int interstitialCount = -1;
    private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ThemeUtils.setTheme(this);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        mHeaderView = (View) findViewById(R.id.header_container);
        mSlidingTabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        mViewPager = (SwipeableViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);


        mAdapter = new NavigationAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), this);

        final Intent intent = getIntent();
        final String action = intent.getAction();

        if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(action)) {
            String data = intent.getDataString();
            ((App) getApplication()).setPushUrl(data);
        }

        //Hiding ActionBar/Toolbar
        if (Config.HIDE_ACTIONBAR)
            getSupportActionBar().hide();
        if (getHideTabs())
            mSlidingTabLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        hasPermissionToDo(this, Config.PERMISSIONS_REQUIRED);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) mViewPager.getLayoutParams();
        if ((Config.HIDE_ACTIONBAR && getHideTabs()) || ((Config.HIDE_ACTIONBAR || getHideTabs()) && getCollapsingActionBar())){
            lp.topMargin = 0;
        } else if ((Config.HIDE_ACTIONBAR || getHideTabs()) || (!Config.HIDE_ACTIONBAR && !getHideTabs() && getCollapsingActionBar())){
            lp.topMargin = getActionBarHeight();
        } else if (!Config.HIDE_ACTIONBAR && !getHideTabs()){
            lp.topMargin = getActionBarHeight() * 2;
        }

        mViewPager.setLayoutParams(lp);

        //Tabs
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(mViewPager.getAdapter().getCount() - 1);

        mSlidingTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
        mSlidingTabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                if (getCollapsingActionBar()) {
                    showToolbar(getFragment());
                }
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
                showInterstitial();
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });

        for (int i = 0; i < mSlidingTabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
            if (Config.ICONS.length > i  && Config.ICONS[i] != 0) {
                mSlidingTabLayout.getTabAt(i).setIcon(Config.ICONS[i]);
            }
        }

        //Drawer
        if (Config.USE_DRAWER) {
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

            DrawerLayout drawer =  ((DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));
            ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                    this, drawer, mToolbar, 0, 0);
            drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
            toggle.syncState();

            //Menu items
            navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
            menu = new SimpleMenu(navigationView.getMenu(), this);
            configureMenu(menu);

            if (Config.HIDE_DRAWER_HEADER) {
                navigationView.getHeaderView(0).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                navigationView.setFitsSystemWindows(false);
            } else {
                if (Config.DRAWER_ICON != R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    ((ImageView) navigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.drawer_icon)).setImageResource(Config.DRAWER_ICON);
                else {
                    ((ImageView) navigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.launcher_icon)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    ((ImageView) navigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.drawer_icon)).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            }
        } else {
            ((DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)).setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
        }

        MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
            }
        });

        //Admob
        if (!getResources().getString(R.string.ad_banner_id).equals("")) {
            // Look up the AdView as a resource and load a request.
            AdView adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).build();
            adView.loadAd(adRequest);
        } else {
            AdView adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
            adView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        if (getResources().getString(R.string.ad_interstitial_id).length() > 0 && Config.INTERSTITIAL_INTERVAL > 0){
            mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
            mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getResources().getString(R.string.ad_interstitial_id));
            AdRequest adRequestInter = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).build();
            mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequestInter);

            mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAdClosed() {
                    // Load the next interstitial.
                    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).build());
                }

            });
        }

        //Application rating
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle(getString(R.string.rate_title))
                .setMessage(String.format(getString(R.string.rate_message), getString(R.string.app_name)))
                .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.rate_yes), null)
                .setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.rate_never), null)
                .setNeutralButton(getString(R.string.rate_later), null);

        new AppRate(this)
                .setShowIfAppHasCrashed(false)
                .setMinDaysUntilPrompt(2)
                .setMinLaunchesUntilPrompt(2)
                .setCustomDialog(builder)
                .init();

        //Showing the splash screen
        if (Config.SPLASH) {
            findViewById(R.id.imageLoading1).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            //getFragment().browser.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        //Toolbar styling
        if (Config.TOOLBAR_ICON != 0) {
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
            ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_icon);
            imageView.setImageResource(Config.TOOLBAR_ICON);
            imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if (!Config.USE_DRAWER){
                imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_START);
            }
        }

    }

    // using the back button of the device
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        View customView = null;
        WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback customViewCallback = null;
        if (getFragment().chromeClient != null) {
            customView = getFragment().chromeClient.getCustomView();
            customViewCallback = getFragment().chromeClient.getCustomViewCallback();
        }

        if ((customView == null)
                && getFragment().browser.canGoBack()) {
            getFragment().browser.goBack();
        } else if (customView != null
                && customViewCallback != null) {
            customViewCallback.onCustomViewHidden();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

        //Adjust menu item visibility/availability based on settings
        if (Config.HIDE_MENU_SHARE) {
            menu.findItem(R.id.share).setVisible(false);
        }
        if (Config.HIDE_MENU_HOME) {
            menu.findItem(R.id.home).setVisible(false);
        }
        if (Config.HIDE_MENU_NAVIGATION){
            menu.findItem(R.id.previous).setVisible(false);
            menu.findItem(R.id.next).setVisible(false);
        }
        if (!Config.SHOW_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS || Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
            menu.findItem(R.id.notification_settings).setVisible(false);
        }

        ThemeUtils.tintAllIcons(menu, this);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        WebView browser = getFragment().browser;
        if (item.getItemId() == (R.id.next)) {
            browser.goForward();
            return true;
        } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.previous) {
            browser.goBack();
            return true;
        } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.share) {
            getFragment().shareURL();
            return true;
        } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.about) {
            AboutDialog();
            return true;
        } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.home) {
            browser.loadUrl(getFragment().mainUrl);
            return true;
        } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.close) {
            finish();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    getText(R.string.exit_message), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.notification_settings){
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction("android.settings.APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS");
            intent.putExtra("app_package", getPackageName());
            intent.putExtra("app_uid", getApplicationInfo().uid);
            intent.putExtra("android.provider.extra.APP_PACKAGE", getPackageName());
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {

        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    /**
     * Showing the About Dialog
     */
    private void AboutDialog() {
        // setting the dialogs text, and making the links clickable
        final TextView message = new TextView(this);
        // i.e.: R.string.dialog_message =>
        final SpannableString s = new SpannableString(
                this.getText(R.string.dialog_about));
        Linkify.addLinks(s, Linkify.WEB_URLS);
        message.setTextSize(15f);
        int padding  = Math.round(20 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
        message.setPadding(padding, 15, padding, 15);
        message.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.dialog_about)));
        message.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

        // creating the actual dialog

        AlertDialog.Builder AlertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        AlertDialog.setTitle(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.about)))
                // .setTitle(R.string.about)
                .setCancelable(true)
                // .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info)
                .setPositiveButton("ok", null).setView(message).create().show();
    }

    /**
     * Set the ActionBar Title
     * @param title title
     */
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        if (mAdapter != null && mAdapter.getCount() == 1 && !Config.USE_DRAWER && !Config.STATIC_TOOLBAR_TITLE)
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
    }

    /**
     * @return the Current WebFragment
     */
    public WebFragment getFragment(){
        return (WebFragment) mAdapter.getCurrentFragment();
    }

    /**
     * Hide the Splash Screen
     */
    public void hideSplash() {
        if (Config.SPLASH) {
            if (findViewById(R.id.imageLoading1).getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                Handler mHandler = new Handler();
                mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        // hide splash image
                        findViewById(R.id.imageLoading1).setVisibility(
                                    View.GONE);
                    }
                    // set a delay before splashscreen is hidden
                }, Config.SPLASH_SCREEN_DELAY);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Hide the toolbar
     */
    public void hideToolbar() {
        if (CurrentAnimation != HIDING) {
            CurrentAnimation = HIDING;
            AnimatorSet animSetXY = new AnimatorSet();

            ObjectAnimator animY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(getFragment().rl, "y", 0);
            ObjectAnimator animY1 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mHeaderView, "y", -getActionBarHeight());
            animSetXY.playTogether(animY, animY1);

            animSetXY.start();
            animSetXY.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    CurrentAnimation = NO;
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {
                }
            });

        }
    }

    /**
     * Show the toolbar
     * @param fragment for which to show the toolbar
     */
    public void showToolbar(WebFragment fragment) {
        if (CurrentAnimation != SHOWING || fragment != CurrentAnimatingFragment) {
            CurrentAnimation = SHOWING;
            CurrentAnimatingFragment = fragment;
            AnimatorSet animSetXY = new AnimatorSet();
            ObjectAnimator animY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(fragment.rl, "y", getActionBarHeight());
            ObjectAnimator animY1 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mHeaderView, "y", 0);
            animSetXY.playTogether(animY, animY1);

            animSetXY.start();
            animSetXY.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    CurrentAnimation = NO;
                    CurrentAnimatingFragment = null;
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {
                }
            });

        }
    }

    public int getActionBarHeight() {
        int mHeight = mToolbar.getHeight();

        //Just in case we get a unreliable result, get it from metrics
        if (mHeight == 0){
            TypedValue tv = new TypedValue();
            if (getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.actionBarSize, tv, true))
            {
                mHeight = TypedValue.complexToDimensionPixelSize(tv.data,getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            }
        }

        return mHeight;
    }

    boolean getHideTabs(){
        if (mAdapter.getCount() == 1 || Config.USE_DRAWER){
            return true;
        } else {
            return Config.HIDE_TABS;
        }
    }

    public static boolean getCollapsingActionBar(){
        if (Config.COLLAPSING_ACTIONBAR && !Config.HIDE_ACTIONBAR){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Check permissions on app start
     * @param context
     * @param permissions Permissions to check
     * @return if the permissions are available
     */
    private static boolean hasPermissionToDo(final Activity context, final String[] permissions) {
        boolean oneDenied = false;
        for (String permission : permissions) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M &&
                    ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission)
                            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                oneDenied = true;
        }

        if (!oneDenied) return true;

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builder.setMessage(R.string.common_permission_explaination);
        builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.common_permission_grant, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                // Fire off an async request to actually get the permission
                // This will show the standard permission request dialog UI
                if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
                    context.requestPermissions(permissions,1);
            }
        });
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Show an interstitial ad
     */
    public void showInterstitial(){
        if (interstitialCount == (Config.INTERSTITIAL_INTERVAL - 1)) {
            if (mInterstitialAd != null && mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                mInterstitialAd.show();
            }

            interstitialCount = 0;
        } else {
            interstitialCount++;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Configure the navigationView
     * @param menu to modify
     */
    public void configureMenu(SimpleMenu menu){
        for (int i = 0; i < Config.TITLES.length; i++) {
            //The title
            String title = null;
            Object titleObj = Config.TITLES[i];
            if (titleObj instanceof Integer && !titleObj.equals(0)) {
                title = getResources().getString((int) titleObj);
            } else {
                title = (String) titleObj;
            }

            //The icon
            int icon = 0;
            if (Config.ICONS.length > i)
                icon = Config.ICONS[i];

            menu.add((String) Config.TITLES[i], icon, new Action(title, Config.URLS[i]));
        }

        menuItemClicked(menu.getFirstMenuItem().getValue(), menu.getFirstMenuItem().getKey());
    }

    @Override
    public void menuItemClicked(Action action, MenuItem item) {
        if (WebToAppWebClient.urlShouldOpenExternally(action.url)){
            //Load url outside WebView
            try {
                startActivity(
                        new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(action.url)));
            } catch(ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                if (action.url.startsWith("intent://")) {
                    startActivity(
                            new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(action.url.replace("intent://", "http://"))));
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, getResources().getString(R.string.no_app_message), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        } else {
            //Uncheck all other items, check the current item
            for (MenuItem menuItem : menu.getMenuItems())
                menuItem.setChecked(false);
            item.setChecked(true);

            //Close the drawer
            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

            //Load the url
            if (getFragment() == null) return;
            getFragment().browser.loadUrl("about:blank");
            getFragment().setBaseUrl(action.url);

            //Show intersitial if applicable
            showInterstitial();
            Log.v("INFO", "Drawer Item Selected");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not comprehensive solution for sure, but I just implement these kind of features for my own app.

If you just want to limit the frequency of the ads showing, in AdMob, you can set limit how often per time unit the add can be shown. [AdMob help for setting frequency capping](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6244508?hl=en)

Another way of limiting the ads could be achieved using probability.

Add proper probability value for your case like this to make ad to shown only every once in a while:

```
private void showInterstitial(Boolean AdsEnabled) {

    final int random = new Random().nextInt(101);

    if(random > 95 && AdsEnabled){
        if (mInterstitialAd != null && mInterstitialAd.isLoaded() ) {
            mInterstitialAd.show();
            Log.i("ads","Interstiade ad shown");
        } else {
            //Do something else
            Log.i("ads","Interstiade ad was not loaded");
        }

    

 }
```

}

You can tune your ads to show up more natural using both of these features.

**And for why you don't see any ads right now**. I might be too beginner my self too, to see why this is the case. But I would add this kind of loader for each backspace press to make sure the ad is loaded. At least I have seen, that sometimes ads fails to load, and this works for me. I have this piece of code used every time I try to show the add.

```
        if (!mInterstitialAd.isLoading() && !mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
        Log.i("ads", "Loading new add, because there was no ad ready");
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
    }
```

It sees to me, that you load the ad when you initialise the ad, and at ad close. But if the ad fails to load at oncreate, do you have the ad close events at all to reload the ad?

I also wonder this

```
public void showInterstitial(){
    if (interstitialCount == (Config.INTERSTITIAL_INTERVAL - 1)) {
```

this shows the ad only when these values are equal. So are you sure that Config.INTERSTITIAL_INTERVAL is at least 1? I think you should change "==" to ">=" to make sure you show the ads even if the INTERSTITIAL_INTERVAL is zero or negative. Or get rid of the minus 1 and keep Config.INTERSTITIAL_INTERVAL positive integer. You have interstitialCount initialised -1 at beginning so this should so the first ad one click later than the next ads, but again, I'm not sure why the ads are not shown right now.

I hope these answers helped you. But as I said, I'm still beginner my self.

-Jussi